# How Big Would We Be in a Venus-Sized Earth?

Tags: evolution, gravity, terraforming, alternate-earth

In the foreseeable future, we have found an alternate Earth with the same gravity, width, density and mass as Venus, but the core and atmospheric pressure are the same size as our Earth's.  Since it is lifeless, it is the perfect opportunity to terraform this planet.

But since this alternate Earth is smaller than our Earth, any plant, fungus, animal and human colonists would grow bigger.  But how big would the average human be in an Earth as small as Venus?

Comment: The difference between Earth and Venus is so small (5% in radius 10% in gravity), that it would hardly matter

Comment: Not certain about Venus, but I'd quite like to know what the limits of our increase in height on *Earth* could be over time, diet and epigenetics'll  play their parts.

Comment: Bit confused.  The planet has the same gravity and width (Diameter?) and density of Earth, but is smaller?  And if everything about it is the same, why would things grow bigger?  And why is it lifeless?  How do you know it's lifeless?

Comment: I don't believe there is good information to support answers on this, even if Venus were significantly different from Earth in size or surface gravity.

Comment: @Trevor Reiterating for clarity: "the same gravity, width, density and mass as Venus." Since OP states the world in question is lifeless, then it is lifeless.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the size of an organism doesn't increase or decrease because of a planet's gravity.   The reason for the dinosaurs growing to their immense size and the large bugs that predated the dinosaurs is thought to be because of a more oxygen saturated atmosphere.   Today's atmosphere is about 20% Oxygen, but when terrestrial life (mostly athropods) first started colonizing land, Oxygen was about 30% of the atmosphere by concentration.   There are several other environmental factors that have numerous different reasons for emerging, such as availability of certain foods as well as genetic factors (I think every set of identical twins I have met has always had a "big" brother/sister and a "little" one despite being genetically identical.).

Comment: Better double check your atmosphere data.  Last I checked, Earth has about 20-21% oxygen, not 10%.

Comment: And we have NO DATA to indicate whether animals and plants grow bigger in different gravity -- because we've never seen them grow anywhere other than Earth.

Comment: @ZeissIkon:  You're right on the first part.  Will amend... Got my figure confused with 10% drop...   It's the AM... Still dopey.   As to the second, the reason why Astronauts have exercise equipment on the space station is to prevent bone and muscle mass from weakening while in a micro gravity environment.   The height boost received is from the spine expanding in a weightless environment but this can be experienced to a smaller degree on earth every morning when you wake up (8 hours of lying down allows the spine to expand, you are slightly taller in the AM than the PM).

Comment: The extension of the spine in microgravity is unrelated to how tall a creature would grow if born in low gravity -- and it's very likely that 10% difference isn't enough difference to notice, compared to other evolutionary pressures that control size (like food availability, predators types/numbers, habitat).

Answer (score 0):

**According to evolution: as big as they needs to be in order to survive and reproduce**

On earth the size of plants and animals vary greatly. Both mice and elephants thrive in their respective environment. I don't think there is much suggesting that mice would be better off if they were bigger, nor elephants if they were smaller. Same for plants, we have small flowers and huge trees.

As such, I'd argue the size of the planet won't change much, it depends on other evolutionary factors. The traits that are best for survival and reproduction are going to be the ones that thrive. That doesn't inherently have to be size.